# How change size textlabel in UITableView

Tags: uitableview

i have problem. I have dynamic tableview. So i need change text size in my textLabel.
I tried:

one:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0f];
```

two:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

three:

```
UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 30.0 ];
cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;
```

But my textlabel not changing. So detailtextlabel - change perfectly but text label - no. What i do wrong? thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the text in the `textLabel` afterwards?

Comment: wats detailtextlabel ??

Comment: Detail text label - it's standard text in tableview for example description...

Comment: I suggest to keep the text size fixed and let the height of the tableview to be dynamic. If you are okay with this let me know to help you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with the following..

but make sure you write this code before u setting your text

```
cell.textLabel.text=@"Your TEXT Goes Here";

UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 18.0 ];
cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I paste this code before...    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(! cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
  
    cell.textLabel.text=@"Your TEXT Goes Here";
    
    UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 11.0 ];
    cell.textLabel.font  = myFont; but nothing

Comment: Hey..there is nothing wrong in code..its working perfectly..am sure your textlabel text is been assigned again somewhere after you setting your size of font and that's reset your fontsize to default

Comment: Can you send your project with working code? if it's possible.

Comment: or just send cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Yes i send cellForRowAtIndexPath method and in this code i tried changed size of my text label

Comment: Hm i open another project and this code work perfectly...so i have mistake in my main project